# Scala - methods conditionally implemented in trait?

Tags: scala

I am looking for the cleanest way to allow user to choose implementation of a method without repeating myself. in the situation below, each of the subclasses put together a greeting in XML with parameters from the specific class. thus the method `toXML` is declared abstract in the trait. What I want, however is to check if a `_generalMessage` was passed in in the construction of the class, and if so, use a general XML greeting common to all implementations of Greeting, e.g. `<Message>_generalMessage</Message>`. I know I can just pattern match on the existence of `_generalMessage` in each of the implementations of `Greeting`, but I am curious if there is a more elegant way.

```scala
trait Greeting {
  protected var foo = //...
  protected var _generalMessage: Option[Srting] = None
  //...
  //public API
  def generalMessage: String = _generalMessage match {case Some(x) => x; case None =>""
  def generalMessage_=(s: String) {_generalMessage = Some(s)}

  protected def toXML: scala.xml.Node

}

class specificGreeting1 extends Greeting {
  // class implementation
  def toXML: scala.xml.Node = <//a detailed XML with values from class specificGreeting1>
}
// multiple other specificGreeting classes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `toXML` final, and define it in the base trait:

```
  final def toXML = _generalMessage.fold(specific message) { m =>
       <Message>m</Message>
  }
```

Then define `specificMessage` in your subclasses to be what you currently have as `toXML`.

Comment: beautifully functional answer